# Elasticsearch highlight complete word instead of query string

Tags: elasticsearch, yii2

i'm trying to implement autocomplete with elasticsearch and yii2 framework. I'm getting the search result but substring highlighting is not working, for example, if I search **uni** it returns "**United** States" instead of "**Uni**ted States". Here is the index setting:

```
'settings' => [
    'number_of_shards' => 1,
    'analysis' => [
        'analyzer' => [
            "autocomplete" => [
                "type" => "custom",
                "tokenizer" => "standard",
                "filter" => ["lowercase", "autocomplete_filter"],
            ],
        ],
        'filter' => [
            "autocomplete_filter" => [
                "type" => "edge_ngram",
                "min_gram" => 2,
                "max_gram" => 15,
            ],
        ],

    ],
],

'properties' => [
    'id'       => ['type' => 'integer'],
    'name'     => [
        'type' => 'string',
        "analyzer" => "autocomplete",
        "search_analyzer" => "standard",

    ],
    'email'    => ['type' => 'string'],
]
```

Please tell how can I achieve this.

Comment: i looked into this before out this is not possible in elastic, highlighting is worked on fields data. check the official autocomplete search by elastic and inspect the network respect and you will observe their api also returns full highlighted words and they handle the highlight part on the frontend in JS(they changed/removed the JS part from frontend to use to highlighted text from API ).

Comment: Can u suggest me any example how to do this in frontend using JavaScript.

Comment: on frontend use jquery to build the highlighted string. This http://garysieling.github.io/jquery-highlighttextarea is a good jquery based plugin to add highlight for text area and input field. You will have input string.

Comment: Thanks i'll try this.